# Find items within a list which exist in another list

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

I have two entity models-

```
public SalesPerson
{
   int PersonId; int DistributionHouseId;
{

public SalesRecord
{
   int RecordId; int PersonId; datetime SalesDate;
{

var persons = Db.SalesPersons.Where(m => m.DistributionHouseId == 1).ToList();

var salesRecords = Db.SalesRecords.Where(m => 
                       persons.Any(x => x.PersonId==m.PersonId) 
                       && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.SalesDate) == date)
                       .ToList();
```

It gives me exception `Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Comment: Your `SalesRecord` has two `RecordId`, and both classes have `{` at the end of the class in place of `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is with the date comparison, sometimes LINQ can translate DBFunction right.

try this:

```
    var salesRecords = Db.SalesRecords.Where(m =>
    persons.Any(x => x.PersonId == m.PersonId))
    .ToList()
    .where(m=> m.SalesDate.Date == date);
```

when the .ToList method is used it loads the data from SQL to the memory, there you can compare the dates

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is this condition:

```
persons.Any(x => x.PersonId==m.PersonId)
```

You can rework it as follows:

```
var personIds = Db.SalesPersons
    .Where(m => m.DistributionHouseId == 1)
    .Select(p => PersonId)
    .ToList();
```

Then the corresponding part of the condition would become

```
personIds.Contains(m.PersonId)
```

which is now a condition that uses a collection of primitive types.